# Postgresql 9.6 concatenation of varchar

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I wonder why concatenation of two varchar gives me text type in result.

```
select 'Plural'::varchar || 'sight'::varchar;
```

Type 'text' of concatenation I see in output of PGAdmin3 (server: 9.4).

Comment: also you dont need pgadmin for defining the type: ` select pg_typeof('Plural'::varchar || 'sight'::varchar);`

Answer (score 8):

```
test=> \doS ||
                                             List of operators
┌────────────┬──────┬───────────────┬────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│   Schema   │ Name │ Left arg type │ Right arg type │ Result type │             Description             │
├────────────┼──────┼───────────────┼────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────┤
│ pg_catalog │ ||   │ anyarray      │ anyarray       │ anyarray    │ concatenate                         │
│ pg_catalog │ ||   │ anyarray      │ anyelement     │ anyarray    │ append element onto end of array    │
│ pg_catalog │ ||   │ anyelement    │ anyarray       │ anyarray    │ prepend element onto front of array │
│ pg_catalog │ ||   │ anynonarray   │ text           │ text        │ concatenate                         │
│ pg_catalog │ ||   │ bit varying   │ bit varying    │ bit varying │ concatenate                         │
│ pg_catalog │ ||   │ bytea         │ bytea          │ bytea       │ concatenate                         │
│ pg_catalog │ ||   │ jsonb         │ jsonb          │ jsonb       │ concatenate                         │
│ pg_catalog │ ||   │ text          │ anynonarray    │ text        │ concatenate                         │
│ pg_catalog │ ||   │ text          │ text           │ text        │ concatenate                         │
│ pg_catalog │ ||   │ tsquery       │ tsquery        │ tsquery     │ OR-concatenate                      │
│ pg_catalog │ ||   │ tsvector      │ tsvector       │ tsvector    │ concatenate                         │
└────────────┴──────┴───────────────┴────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
(11 rows)
```

There is no `||` operator for `varchar`. What happens is that PostgreSQL casts the `varchar` to `text` (that is the preferred type in this type category).

The result of the operation will then be `text` as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Table 9-8. SQL String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

> `string || string` - return type text

Also read on type [Type conversion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-oper.html), Eg **String Concatenation Operator Type Resolution**.

And also I text is default string type for postgres, so when you mix data types they will default to text for string.

Answer (score 0):

Because they we're created that way :
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html